# Vuejs - Assigning values in a constant

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-rx

I am reviewing an app build in Vuejs (I am not a vue developer), so be patient with me.

I found this line of code:

```
const {property, $rxFirebase: {actions: {properties}}} = this
```

I guess this works as in other languages. "This" is assigning values to the object in the left.

I am trying to read also {sources: {properties}}, so I have added the code like this:

```
const {property, $rxFirebase: {actions: {properties}, sources: {properties}}} = this
```

But when I build it, I get an error:

```
Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "properties"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not just assignment its destructuring assignment.
This line:

```
const {property, $rxFirebase: {actions: {properties}}} = this
```

is equivalent to

```
const property = this.property, properties = this.$rxFirebase.actions.properties;
```

So you can not add another `properties` variable because it is already declared. You should add different name for second `properties` declaration, like this:

```
const {property, $rxFirebase: {actions: {properties}, sources: {properties: myProperties }}} = this; // where myProperties some name for variable
console.log(myProperties === this.$rxFirebase.sources.properties); // true
```

Comment: can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549695/vuejs-how-to-read-data-from-observable it seems a long question, but actually is a direct question, how to get the properiest list count. I just show the code related before asking that.